# Generating combinations of edges under a certain condition

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

I have edges of a graph represented as (node_from, node_to).

I want to efficiently generate all combinations of 2 edges of the form (0,x), where 0 is node 0 in my graph - in combination with all combinations of 2 edges of the form (x,n), where n is the "final node" (arbitrary i know) in my graph.  I already have all the edges sitting around in a set, or also it is the case that every node contains an edge to every other node (so you could directly iterate through the range to generate combinations, for example).

A valid combination could be

- (0,1),(0,5),(7,n),(11,n) or
- (0,1),(0,5),(5,n),(11,n) or
- (0,1),(0,n),(0,n),(11,n)

And, just to make it clear, I want combinations not permutations.  I don't want to re-use the same group.

I am generally pretty good at figuring this stuff out, but I am having a bit of trouble with this one.

Comment: Can you give an example input and the output you'd like to get from that?

Comment: What should be the output? A list of list of 2-tuples I assume?

Comment: Hi brad, willem.  An example input would be a set of edges from 0 to n, where each edge is a tuple of the form (i,j), and i < j.

An example output would be any iterable structure that could hold the combination of 4 edges.  So probably something like a list of tuples, a set of tuples(of tuples), etc etc.  Probably better outputs im not thinking of, but anything goes really.

Comment: I edited my answer, please check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: updated to acommodate the requirements of "only two start/end edges"

I'm not sure what interface you have in mind, but from what I understood it looks like you can use `filter()` to select a subset of edges that "start in `0`" or "end in `n`".

```
>>> edges = [(0,1), (0,5), (0,2), (5,3), (2,9), (4,6), (6,9), (3,9), (0,9)]
>>> edges_start = filter(lambda e: e[0] == 0, edges)
>>> edges_end = filter(lambda e: e[1] == 9, edges)
>>> edges_end
[(2, 9), (6, 9), (3, 9), (0, 9)]
>>> edges_start
[(0, 1), (0, 5), (0, 2), (0, 9)]
```

Now you can use `itertools.combinations()` to generate all possible pairs from each of the lists. Here's an example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations(edges_start, 2))
[((0, 1), (0, 5)), ((0, 1), (0, 2)), ((0, 1), (0, 9)), ((0, 5), (0, 2)), ((0, 5), (0, 9)), ((0, 2), (0, 9))]
```

Now you can plug in `itertools.product()` to generate all combinations of "pair from one list" and "pair from other list":

```
>>> edges_start_pairs = list(itertools.combinations(edges_start, 2))
>>> edges_end_pairs = list(itertools.combinations(edges_end, 2))
>>> pairs = list(itertools.product(edges_start_pairs, edges_end_pairs))
```

That's it! You can "flatten" the data structure if you like, but this is optional:

```
>>> flat_pairs = [list(p[0]+p[1]) for p in pairs]
```

Now let's pretty-print the results:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(flat_pairs)
[[(0, 1), (0, 5), (2, 9), (6, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 5), (2, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 5), (2, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 5), (6, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 5), (6, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 5), (3, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 9), (6, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 2), (6, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 2), (6, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 2), (3, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 9), (2, 9), (6, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 9), (2, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 9), (2, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 9), (6, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 9), (6, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 9), (3, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 2), (2, 9), (6, 9)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 2), (2, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 2), (2, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 2), (6, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 2), (6, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 2), (3, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 9), (2, 9), (6, 9)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 9), (2, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 9), (2, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 9), (6, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 9), (6, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 9), (3, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 2), (0, 9), (2, 9), (6, 9)],
 [(0, 2), (0, 9), (2, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(0, 2), (0, 9), (2, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 2), (0, 9), (6, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(0, 2), (0, 9), (6, 9), (0, 9)],
 [(0, 2), (0, 9), (3, 9), (0, 9)]]
```